# undefined reference to `log2f@GLIBC_2.27' undefined reference to `logf@GLIBC_2.27'

Tags: lm, lapack, math.h

I'am trying to a run a sample code from pardiso website but end up with this error.
I installed the lapack package from http://www.netlib.org/lapack/

```
gcc pardiso_sym.c -L /home/sree/ -lpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64 -llapack  -lgfortran -fopenmp -lm -ldl
```

error:

```
/home/sree//libpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `log2f@GLIBC_2.27'
/home/sree//libpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64.so: undefined reference to `logf@GLIBC_2.27'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old but anyway:

First of all - the error you are getting is a linker error and is seems like it cannot resolve a reference to a function defined in glibc.

The version given here for glibc (the [GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) is 2.27.

I would now suspect that the version used by GCC when trying to compile pardiso_sym.c was lower than the specified version of glibc - thus the error.

You can find a nice thread about checking the version of glibc used by different gcc compilers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614769/how-to-i-find-the-filename-of-a-library-via-the-library-name).

That said - different gcc compilers might use different versions of glibc for linking. You could now either specifically try and link a proper version of glibc ([like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)) or - probably more feasible - try and [update your glibc version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736208/upgrading-glibc).

The described pardiso packages were also compiled with gcc 8.0 but there is a pardiso version available compiled using the gcc 7.2. Both versions also link agains different glibc versions and it might already be feasible to use libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so.
In addition I'd also use a gcc version that is higher equal than the one used to compile pardiso so you might want to upgrade gcc too.

**Edit:**
Originally Pardiso 6.0 (and, for that matter also 6.2) was deployed as either `libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so` or `libpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64.so` both available under its Download-Link.

Comment: I had the same problem as OP. Your suggestion to use "a gcc version that is higher equal than the one used to compile pardiso" didn't help, I used GCC 10.2 (!). Trying to find a fix, I'll post it if successful.

Comment: Did you check what version of glibc you GCC is trying to link against Pardiso? And did you try the GNU729 pardiso executable?

Comment: Yes, I did: Pardiso wants Version 2.27, I have Version 2.17 (checked with `ldd --version`). No, I don't have the `GNU729` Pardiso executable. Only thing I have is Version 6.0, see above. *However*: I contacted Prof. Olaf Schenk (creator of Pardiso) and he kindly promised to give me a new Version 7.2 library compiled against a sufficiently old `glibc` which I expect to solve the problem.

Comment: Both versions are 6.0 executables (one could choose them when downloading PARDISO, for 6.0 there was `libpardiso600-GNU729-X86-64.so` and `libpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64.so` available). The difference was that they were linked with different a gcc and a different gclib version. Probably that was not very clear in my answer - I'll update that. But good everything worked out.

Comment: Yes, the `GNU720` (not `GNU729` btw) version did the trick for me. Link line details in my answer, and a big thank you to "Flusslauf" (i.e. +1 :-) )

Comment: Uhh - my bad.. I'll change that to 720, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here comes the summary of what I learned:

The Pardiso library (like all shared libraries) remembers which `glibc` version was used when it was compiled. Occasionally `glibc` may be older on your system than what Pardiso expects, leading to the link errors described by OP. You can check the version of your `glibc` by running `ldd --version`.

I applied for a free time-limited academic license, that gave me a personal download link. As @Flusslauf pointed out, one has the choice of 2 versions for the Linux 64-bit platform. As of today (2021-03-03) the two versions available to me were: `libpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64.so` (note: `GNU720` and not `GNU729`, but that's a minor difference) and `libpardiso600-GNU800-X86-64.so`. The latter didn't work for me for the reasons explained above. So I compiled one of the little example programs from the Pardiso website in the directory containing the former Pardiso library as follows:

```sh
cd /path/to/pardiso
gcc pardiso_sym.c -L/usr/lib64 -L. -lpardiso600-GNU720-X86-64 \
  -llapack -lblas -fopenmp -lpthread -lm -ldl -o psym
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/pardiso:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export PARDISOLICMESSAGE=1
./psym
```

The `-L/usr/lib64` was necessary to find LAPACK and BLAS on the machine I used. The `-L.` tells GCC to look for the Pardiso library in the current directory (`/path/to/pardiso` where I compiled the test program). After compilation, add to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the Pardiso library location, ask for 2 OpenMP threads and silence the Pardiso license message.

Oh, one last thing: don't forget to copy your license file to your home directory! :-)